# Morris.js displaying incorrect line graph with Django template array

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, morris.js

I recently heard of Morris.js and attempted to include a line graph in a website I was working on. However, whenever I feed elements from my dates array to the data component of Morris.line(), the graph fails to display properly and instead displays a bunch of weird dates.

The relevant snippet of my JS code is shown here:

```
    Morris.Line({
        element: 'line',
        data: [
            { d: {{ dates.0 }}, v: {{ polar.0 }}},
            { d: {{ dates.1 }}, v: {{ polar.1 }}},
            { d: {{ dates.2 }}, v: {{ polar.2 }}},
            { d: {{ dates.3 }}, v: {{ polar.3 }}},
            { d: {{ dates.4 }}, v: {{ polar.4 }}},
        ],
        xkey: 'd',
        ykeys: ['v'],
        labels: ['Polarity']
    });
```

And the result can be seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T98FO.png

The dates that were supplied to the line graph were simply '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', and '2009', in order to test the functionality of the graph. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was solved by surrounding the `{{ dates.x }}` elements in quotes and by including the `parseTime: false` parameter in the function.